# ViewGroup transmits to its children 'onPressed' state

Tags: android, touch, gallery

I have a Gallery and a custom layout for its items. There are two buttons on each. Every time I touch an item View, its buttons become pressed.

When I click a button, another one doesn't receive onPressed state, however both of them receive it when I click near by.

How to prevent changing state of untouched buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already had an overridden class as container where the buttons are. So the way it was mentioned by Luksprog I override setPressed()

```
public class GalleryItem extends FrameLayout {
    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {

        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Buttons` in the item layout with the custom `Button` class below and see if the behavior still exists after:

```
public class SpecialButton extends Button {

    // implement constructors

    @Override
    public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
        if (pressed && (getParent() instanceof View) && ((View) getParent()).isPressed()) {
            return;
        }
        super.setPressed(pressed);
    }

}
```